# jquery swap div content with actions from plugins

Tags: jquery

I know it should be an easy thing... I want to swap content of 2 divs, with remain action binded to each element. Now I have this:

```
<div class="From">
    //something here, doesnt matter
</div>

<div class="To">
    //something here, doesnt matter
</div>
....
function switchElems() {
    var from = $( ".From" );
    var to = $( ".To" );
    var fromHtml = from.html();
    var toHtml = to.html();
    from.html( toHtml );
    to.html( fromHtml );
}
```

But it only switches content, unbinding every action connected with elements inside.
By actions I mean whole logic included into content inside, appended by additional plugins. For example inside div with class `from` there is `input` with jQuery geocomplete plugin binded into it. After switching elems, I'd like that input to still have geocomplete functionallity, but now `input` should be in `div` named `To`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post code with those actions ?

Comment: What action is being done that you want it to switch? i.e. Keydown? Select Option change?

Comment: Actually those actions are plugins. One is jQuery geocomplete binded to input field. Second one is Select2 plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind events to elements inside each div. That way even when you change `div`'s HTML, event listeners will work.

For example:

```
$('#from').on('click', '.my-element', handler);
```

In this case if you update content of #from and new my-elements show up in it, they will have handler

Also `switch` is a reseved word in JavaScript, you shouldn't name you function `switch`.

Comment: That would be easy for simple actions. What when I have input with binded plugin into it? (jQuery Geocomplete)

Comment: If your plugin allows event delegation do use it. If not, edit your plugin.

Answer (score 0):

For one, your classes were missing `"` at the end

Html:

```
<div class="From">
    //something here, doesnt matter
</div>
<div class="To">
     //something here, doesnt matter
 </div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('class_or_id').change(function(){
     var from = $( ".From" );
     var to = $( ".To" );
     var fromHtml = from.html();
     var toHtml = to.html();
     from.html( toHtml );
     to.html( fromHtml );
});
```

OR

```
$('class_or_id').click(function(){
     var from = $( ".From" );
     var to = $( ".To" );
     var fromHtml = from.html();
     var toHtml = to.html();
     from.html( toHtml );
     to.html( fromHtml );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the elements, then don't use `html()`, which converts everything to a string, but move the native elements around instead:

```
$('class_or_id').click(function(){
    var from = $(".From"),
        to = $(".To"),
        fromContents = from.contents(),
        toContents = to.contents();

    to.append(fromContents);
    from.append(toContents);
});
```